# How to change row into column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I change this table

```
Name      subject     Mark
Aswin     physics     100
Aswin     chemistry   300
Aswin     maths       200
```

Into

```
Aswin Physics 100 Chemistry 300 Maths 200
```

Any one please help me.

Comment: not straight forward, need to values to a temp table and the select from there

Comment: what if you use separate table for subject having 1 to many relation ship and then you can get your required result using sub query..

Answer (score 2):

you can use PIVOT operator to do this job in sql server.

check these links [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [link2](http://blog.jontav.com/post/8344518585/convert-rows-to-columns-columns-to-rows-in-sql-server) they will show how to change row into column.

hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18ea6/6)

```
select Name,
       sum(CASE 
          when [subject]='physics' then Mark
       end) as Physics,
       sum(CASE 
          when [subject]='chemistry' then Mark
       end) as chemistry,
       sum(CASE 
          when [subject]='maths' then Mark
       end) as maths


from t group by Name
```

Or if you need it in one line:

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18ea6/16)

```
SELECT
   t1.name,
   MemberList = substring((SELECT ( ', ' + subject+' - '+
                                   cast(Mark as varchar(100)) )
                           FROM t t2
                           WHERE t1.name = t2.name
                           ORDER BY 
                              name,
                              subject
                           FOR XML PATH( '' )
                          ), 3, 1000 )FROM t t1
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SQL Pivoting, check the examples at [SQL SERVER – PIVOT and UNPIVOT Table Examples](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/). Using Sql Pivoting you can change the rows to columns and Unpivoting is for columns to rows conversion.

Please note: I am checking if I can provide you exact script but for now the link would help you out.

### UPDATE

**Code example**
Though I have not tested this with actual data but it parses fine.

```
-- Pivot Table ordered by Name of Student
SELECT Name, Physics, Chemistry, Maths
FROM (
SELECT Name, Subject, Mark
FROM Student) up
PIVOT (SUM(Mark) FOR Student IN (Physics, Chemistry, Maths)) AS pvt
ORDER BY Name

-- Result should be something like
----------------------------------
Name   Physics   Chemistry   Maths
----------------------------------
Aswin  100       300         200

----------------------------------
```

For creating pivot you need to know the actual rows values to convert into columns.
I have wrote before about dynamic pivoting [here](http://baidharsh.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/implementing-sql-dynamic-pivot-query/) if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear if you want this data in separate columns or in one column.

If you want this in separate columns, then you can apply the `PIVOT` function which became available in SQL Server 2005.

If you know all of the values that you want to transform or have a limited number, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select *
from
(
  select name, subject +' '+ cast(mark as varchar(9)) as sub_mark,
    'Subject_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by name 
                                     order by subject) as varchar(10)) col_name
  from subjects
) s
pivot
(
  max(sub_mark)
  for col_name in (Subject_1, Subject_2, Subject_3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60283/16). You will notice that I did this slightly different from the other *pivot* answer. I placed both the subject/mark in the same column with a column name of `Subject_1`, etc.

If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Subject_'+cast(row_number() over(partition by name 
                                     order by subject) as varchar(10))) 
                    from subjects
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select name, subject +'' ''+ cast(mark as varchar(9)) as sub_mark,
                  ''Subject_''+cast(row_number() over(partition by name 
                                                   order by subject) as varchar(10)) col_name
                from subjects
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
              max(sub_mark)
              for col_name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60283/17). The dynamic sql version will increase in the number of columns if a `name` has more than 3 subjects.

The result of both queries is:

```
|  NAME |     SUBJECT_1 | SUBJECT_2 |   SUBJECT_3 |
---------------------------------------------------
| Aswin | chemistry 300 | maths 200 | physics 100 |
```